# Stateful Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Presently, I am learning the flutter framework for android development.
I came across this sentence " The StatefulWidget class is, itself, immutable, but the State class persists over the lifetime of the widget ".
I don't have much idea about the widget concept. So, Can someone explain to me, what does this sentence mean?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45945202/6706175

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What difference between stateless and stateful widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45936084/what-difference-between-stateless-and-stateful-widgets)